# Trigger rebuilding index after it exceed given fragmentation level

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Because I have to maintain couple databases and over 1000 tables heavily loaded of DML operations I had a thought to maintain indexes fragmentation level below some value automatically using triggers.

It's only thought I don't have time now to do it so no my code will be provided. Of course I have some general schema in my mind how to do it. I'm able to build a trigger, I know how to find indexes fragmentation value. But without lot of testing and extensive documentation reading I don't know how to do it less buggy and the most optimal as possible. It could be even imposibble because I know little of triggers and their restrictions and some operations needed to achive this task could be disallowed in trigger.

On example some things bothers me:

- use online or offline indexes
- does such trigger can crash the query
- because of timeout is there possibility to perform trigger not after 
  some single row update but when the full query is finished so it can't crush because of index rebuild in a fly

So how to achieve such task in most optimal manner? Any info about how such trigger influence queries performance will also be appreciated.

**EDIT:**
Because of request I'll provide some code. It could be full solution but it generates error message when trigger is triggered: *'Cannot execute ALTER INDEX on/using table 'schema.table' since the table is the target table or part of cascading actions of a currently executing trigger'*

```
CREATE TRIGGER defragmentator ON [schema].[table]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
    DECLARE @fragRate float;

    SELECT @fragRate = a.avg_fragmentation_in_percent
    FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(N'MyDB'), OBJECT_ID(N'[schema].[table]'), NULL, NULL, NULL) AS a
    JOIN sys.indexes AS b ON a.object_id = b.object_id AND a.index_id = b.index_id
    WHERE b.name = 'IDX_name';

    IF @fragRate > 50
    ALTER INDEX IDX_name ON [schema].[table]
    REBUILD
GO
```

How to improve that?

Comment: Sorry to be terse, but if you don't have time to rough out some code with your intended approach I can't find time to write a full solution for you.

Comment: Ok, I will provide some code when I reach home (I'm leaving my company right now)

Comment: I provided solution but it generates an error

Answer (score 3):

It's bad idea. Index operations should be performed during the maintenance windows defined by your business. SQL Agent with scheduled jobs is much more preferrable solution.

Comment: Is this remote tool which I can use on local computer or direct access to the server is needed?

Comment: ALTER INDEX in a trigger a bad idea? Terrible more like.

Comment: What do you mean by remote tool? SSMS is all what you need. On local computer, if you have remote access to SQL Server instance.

Comment: This was te answer I needed. I don't have access to the system on which SQL Server is installed. Remote I mean used the same way as SSMS because this is only app I use to connect with server.

Comment: Could you connect to your remote server from SSMS on local computer?

Comment: Yes I can. I've just said that it is the only way I can use it.

Comment: Great. So you just need to create appropriate SQL Server Agent Job. Do you need a help with this?